# Tinydns data file change ip with bash

Tags: bash, regex, sed, awk, tinydns

I am using tinydns and need to dynamicly change some ip in data file. I want to use bash script for it.

For example data file:

```
+sub1.example.org:282.196.222.245:14400
+sub2.example.org:278.179.280.253:14400
+sub3.example.org:285.117.214.234:14400
```

bash script has two variables:

```
old="282.196.222.245"
new="127.0.0.1"
```

I expect this result:

```
+sub1.example.org:127.0.0.1:14400
+sub2.example.org:278.179.280.253:14400
+sub3.example.org:285.117.214.234:14400
```

What is the best way to replace old ip to new (using awk, sed or smth else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed -i "s/$old/$new/g" filename
```

Here you have simple test:

```
# echo "+sub1.example.org:282.196.222.245:14400" >> filename

# cat filename
+sub1.example.org:282.196.222.245:14400

# old=282.196.222.245
# new=127.0.0.1

# sed -i "s/$old/$new/g" filename

# cat filename
+sub1.example.org:127.0.0.1:14400<br>
```

Comment: "g" is not needed normaly but is absolutely not an issue

Comment: You're right, it's my habit just like '>>' instead of '>' - I use it too often ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's cleaner to avoid trying to monkey-patch `data`; instead, generate your `data` from several files, one of which only contains the dynamic record(s).

Then, from bash, you can just `echo "+sub3.example.org:285.117.214.234:14400" >data.dynamic; make` or similar.

Example Makefile:

```
data.cdb : data 
    tinydns-data

data : data.static data.dynamic
    cat data.static data.dynamic >data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v "old=$old" -v "new=$new" '$2 == old {$2 = new} {print}' filename > tempfile && mv tempfile filename
```

or

```
awk -v "old=$old" -v "new=$new" '$2 == old {$2 = new}1' filename > tempfile && mv tempfile filename
```